# How can I convert this UTF8 code in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, utf-8, encode

I am using an API that's giving me names in Chinese. When I create a label, I do something like:

```
label.text = [[savedArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForkey:@"name"];
```

The label will have the correct name in Chinese (e.g. 市政府). Now I am trying to add this text into another NSMutableArray with:

```
[array addObject:label.text];
NSLog(@"%@",array);
```

NSLog prints something like:

```
"\U65b0\U5317\U5e02\U7acb\U5716\U66f8\U9928\U4e09\U91cd\U5206\U9928",
"\U4e09\U5f35\U516c\U5712"
```

***I am not sure if this is UTF8 or Big5 as my knowledge in this category is poor***. I tried

```
[array addObject:[NSString stringWithCString:[label.text cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

but I get the same result. How can I have NSLog print out the same result as label.text? What I want to do is to be able to have all the names in one single array for future usage.

Comment: loop the array and print each item.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I want to have all the names within an array so I can use the data as an array.